# Html Agility Pack not able to read xpath correctly?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am making a web scraper app in C#. I am using Html Agility Pack to parse an html. I am starting to doubt its functionality, as there seems to be nodes it cannot select.

Here is the site I am trying to scrape: https://place.map.kakao.com/253560122

```
<div id='kakaoWrap'>
  <div class='kakaoContent'>
    <div id='mArticle'>
      <div data-viewid='menuInfo'>
        <ul class='list_menu'>
          <li class='nophoto_type'>
          <li class='nophoto_type'>
          <li class='nophoto_type'>
...
```

I am trying to grab the list items in the `<ul class='list_menu'>`. If I use the `$x` function in the Google Chrome console, it selects three li elements as expected:

```
$x("//*[@class='nophoto_type']")
(3) [li.nophoto_type, li.nophoto_type, li.nophoto_type]
0: li.nophoto_type
1: li.nophoto_type
2: li.nophoto_type
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So I use the same xpath in C#, but it fails to select anything:

```
var menus = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='nophoto_type']");
```

I am trying to see where the error occurs by trying to reach the list incrementally. As I've found out, it can select `(div id='kakaoWrap'), but not (div class='kakaoContent')`:

```
var menus = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body/div[@id='kakaoWrap']") // Works!;
var menus = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body/div[@id='kakaoWrap']/div[@class='kakaoContent']") // Returns null!;
```

My two guesses are 1.) Html Agility Pack is having trouble with xpath, or 2.) the site is actively blocking parsing, guessing from the warning:

A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://t1.daumcdn.net/mapjsapi/js/main/4.2.0/v3.js, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

But I can select the whole document and some nodes inside, so I think its 1.). I always had trouble working with xpaths, I would appreciate if anyone can shed their wisdom if I am not seeing something!

Comment: If you press Ctrl-U in the browser to see the page source, you will see that there is nothing there except for links to scripts which would populate the page. HTML Agility Pack doesn't act as a browser, so it doesn't run those scripts.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the comment, now I see the issue. As you said I found that HtmlAgilityPack can't handle dynamic content with javascript. Do you happen to know any C# libraries capable of doing this?

Comment: Ideally, the web site would have an API to directly get the data. However, you could try adding a web browser control to a form and find some way to get the data out of that.

Comment: Awesome, will see what I can do, thanks man!!